# $\pm 1$ combination of binomial coefficients that gives $0$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

Let $$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$$ be the binomial coefficient where $n\ge 1$, $0\le k\le n$. I am wondering if the following is true

> Let $n\ge 1$ be integers and for any $0\le k\le n$, $\lambda_k\in\mathbb{N}$. Then
> $$\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}(-1)^{\lambda_k}=0$$ if and only if $\lambda_k\equiv k\mod 2$ or $\lambda_k\equiv k+1\mod 2$.

In non-mathematical terms, the only way you can make a $\pm 1$-combination of binomial coefficients to be $0$ is that you arrange the $+1$ and $-1$ alternatively.

The "if" part follows directly from binomial expansion of $$0=(1-1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}(-1)^k.$$

Comment: For any $\lambda$, you either have $\lambda\equiv k$ mod 2 or $\lambda\equiv k+1$ mod 2.

Comment: @GReyes I think there's an implied universal quantifier in the statement of OP.

Comment: This is certainly false as it stands, e.g., $1+3-3-1=0$, $1+5+10-10-5-1=0$, and so on. Also $1-5-10+10+5-1=0$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I see. So the assertion is that $\lambda_k$ should be either of the same parity as $k$ for every $k$ or of the opposite parity for every $k$.. that is false, as your example shows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a somewhat less trivial counterexample than the ones I put in the comments: Let $n=14$, let the exponents be $1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1$.

In numbers, this is $$1-14+91-364-1001+2002-3003-3432+3003+2002+1001-364+91-14+1=0$$